# How return to the first xib view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

First ViewController.xib contains 4 views (without UINavigationController in xib).

1. "ViewController.h" - were here ...
2. "GlavView.h" - got here ...

How to go back to 1 (ViewController.h)?

// Methods

```
- (IBAction) iBM_GlavView:(id)sender;
- (void) iDM_GlavView;
```

These methods are not available in GlavView.m if I did not tie the selector button to the First Responder, but they are available in ViewController.m

If you use Interface Builder, then it works, but I do not want to use Interface Builder, and without it, to reach out to ViewController, I do not know.

Thank you for any help!

**Here is part of the application code:**

--------------- AppDelegate.h

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//
//


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> //UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

--------------- ViewController.h

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}


@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;


- (IBAction) iBM_GlavView:(id)sender;
- (void) iDM_GlavView;

@end
```

--------------- ViewController.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  SeifNote
//
//  Created by Saveliy Severniy on 19.01.12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Saveliy Severniy. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GlavView.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize navigationController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if( isLogin )
    {
        // Ok
        [self iDM_GlavView];
    }
    else
    {

        [self.view addSubview:self.viewEnterPass];
    }
}

- (IBAction)iBM_GlavView:(id)sender{

    if (self.navigationController == nil) {

        //navigationController is declared as: UINavigationController * navigationController;
        navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

        GlavView *myOptions = [[GlavView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GlavView" bundle:nil];

        [navigationController pushViewController:myOptions animated:NO];
        [myOptions release];

    }

    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view]; // From this point begins the work UINavigationController in a new view

}




- (void) iDM_GlavView {

    if (self.navigationController == nil) {

        // navigationController is declared as: UINavigationController *optionsRootController;
        navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

        GlavView *myOptions = [[GlavView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GlavView" bundle:nil];

        [navigationController pushViewController:myOptions animated:NO];
        [myOptions release];

    }

    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
}
```

--------------- GlavView.h

```
//
//  GlavView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GlavView : UITableViewController {
    UIToolbar *toolbar;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem* addButtonItem;

@end
```

--------------- GlavView.m

```
//
//  GlavView.m
//

#import "GlavView.h"

@implementation GlavView

@synthesize addButtonItem;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //  is declared as: UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButtonItem;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Initialize the toolbar
    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

    //Set the toolbar to fit the width of the app.
    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    //Caclulate the height of the toolbar
    CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;

    //Get the bounds of the parent view
    CGRect rootViewBounds = self.parentViewController.view.bounds;

    //Get the height of the parent view.
    CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);

    //Get the width of the parent view,
    CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);

    //Create a rectangle for the toolbar
    CGRect rectArea = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight);

    //Reposition and resize the receiver
    [toolbar setFrame:rectArea];


    //Create a button
    UIBarButtonItem *testButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle:@"Del" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(test_clicked:)];

    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:testButton,nil]];

    [testButton release];

    //Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller.
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

    //Reload the table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void) test_clicked:(id)sender {

    // iBM_GlavView is declared in ViewController.h

    [??? iBM_GlavView]; // How to get out of here (GlavView) and return (ViewController)?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iSavaDevRu, see [navigationController methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated%3a) is for you :)

NSNotificationCenter удобная штука
смотри делай так

```
//добовляем из кода метод к нажатие кнопки

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
-(void)buttonPressed {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BUTTONPRESSED" object:nil];
}

//а потом добавляем в нашем контороллере чтоб вызывался наш метод при вывидение этой нотификаций
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(IBM_DelPass:) name:@"BUTTONPRESSED" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, it does not work for me. [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; Error does not give out, but nowhere does not make the transition. Navigation controller is not used in other views

Comment: your root controller is UIViewController... but you need UINavigationController

Comment: [??? iBM_GlavView]; // How to get out of here (GlavView) and return (ViewController)? The code is explained in the bottom of what you need. A little more closely read what I ask. Thank you.

Comment: This means I will have two controllers UINavigationController?

Comment: easily add in appDelegate a UINavigationController.

Comment: see this http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews

Comment: but you tried [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; ?

Comment: I tried, in this case does not work, I have a wrapper, I have a modal view.

Link looked a standard application that uses UINavigationController. But I need to work without UINavigationController the other xib. My task, to find out how you can jump on without xib UINavigationController. I live in Russia, I am sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге я сделал подробную и ясную инструкцию.
Данный вариант перехода к другому методу выполнен с помощью NSNotificationCenter.

In the end, I made a detailed and clear instructions.
This version of the transition to another method was performed with a NSNotificationCenter.

## ---

Еще есть вариант с Delegate, но его пока не пробовал.

Another option is a Delegate, but it has not yet tried.

## ---

Выполнение метода из любого другого файла

Execution of the method of any other file

**NSNotificationCenter**

```
//##############################################
// (From:) Откуда должны прийти (buttonClick)
//##############################################

// 
// Файл start.m

- (void) start:(id)sender {
    
    NSDictionary *dataInfo = ?data?;    // may be nil
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Info" object:nil userInfo:dataInfo];

    // Or without data

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Info" object:nil];
}


//##########################################
// (To:) Куда должны прийти и выполнить метод
//##########################################

// 
// В файле end.h:

- (void) end: (NSNotification *)notification;

// В файле end.m:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(end:) name:@"Info" object:nil];
}

- (void) end: (NSNotification *)notification {
    
    // The End
}
```